# Duplicating subviews(UIButton and UIImageView) of UITableViewCell contentView on scrolling

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In my tableView, in some cells i have added an imageView as subview of cell contentView. On scrolling tableView up and down these images duplicating on other cells also. But this problem doesn't occur always. Please suggest a solution.. I am using the following code.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    if (friendsArray.count != 0)
    {
        NSString *str = [friendsIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([pendingRequests containsObject:str])
        {
            // Add image for pending item
            UIImageView *pendImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pendng.png"]];
            pendImage.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 2.5, 70, 40);
            pendImage.tag = indexPath.row;   
            [cell.contentView addSubview:pendImage];
        }
    }

}

NSString *object;

if (friendsArray.count == 0)
{
    if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row]) 
    {
        for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    object = @"No friends added to the list";
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
}
else 
{
    object = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

    if (![cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row]) 
    {
        NSString *str = [friendsIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([pendingRequests containsObject:str])
        {
            // Add image for pending item
            UIImageView *pendImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pendng.png"]];
            pendImage.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 2.5, 70, 40);
            pendImage.tag = indexPath.row;   
            [cell.contentView addSubview:pendImage];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is solved now. I have used the following line inside the else case of creating new tableViewCell.

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

I have edited my code as shown below :

```
if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    }
```

Comment: @AnushaK, i tried this way but not working for me, any other solutions? if so please make reply

Comment: customTableViewCell *cell = (customTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    }
im doing this way actually, i tried above ur solution, but not helped

Comment: i fixed, my issue by adding following code     cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %ld",(long)indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code..

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    if (friendsArray.count != 0)
    {
        NSString *str = [friendsIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([pendingRequests containsObject:str])
        {
            // Add image for pending item
            UIImageView *pendImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pendng.png"]];
            pendImage.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 2.5, 70, 40);
            pendImage.tag = indexPath.row;   
            [cell.contentView addSubview:pendImage];
        }
    }


    NSString *object;

    if (friendsArray.count == 0)
    {
       if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row]) 
       {
          for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
          {
             [subview removeFromSuperview];
          }
       }

        object = @"No friends added to the list";
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    else 
    {
       object = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

       if (![cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row]) 
       {
          NSString *str = [friendsIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          if ([pendingRequests containsObject:str])
          {
             // Add image for pending item
             UIImageView *pendImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pendng.png"]];
             pendImage.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 2.5, 70, 40);
             pendImage.tag = indexPath.row;   
             [cell.contentView addSubview:pendImage];
          }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code not worked for me. Still the images are misplaced in different rows on scrolling. Can you suggest any other solution???

Answer (score 0):

As Romit Mewada suggested you can use that but each time you have alloc & add new `UIImageView`.

Instead of that you can send nil to the image of that `UIImageView`.

Implement in this way.

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    //get your cell or alloc & initialize
    // create and add imageView
}

UIImageView* imageView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
imageView.image = nil;
//do your other task, you can use the same imageView to add other image for other row.
```