# issue with a tableview with differen tableview tags

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a problem with my tableview. Let me first sketch the situation. I have a view with on top `2 buttons` (Calendar and Ranking). Below this two buttons I have a tableview. When I press on a button I set the `tableview's tag ( 1 or 2 )` and I reload the tableview's data.

In my ranking I am making one specific cell's text color blue. But when I refresh, other cell's texts are going blue.

Now for my `cellForRowAtIndex` I have a lot of code. Because I don't know excactly where the problem is I will post all the code over here. I hope you don't bother.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //standard cell
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"KalenderCell";
    KalenderCell *cell = (KalenderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass:KalenderCell.class]))
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KalenderCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //Cells for button 2
    if(self.tableView.tag == 2){
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"KlassementCell";

        KlassementCell *cell = (KlassementCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass: KlassementCell.class]))
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KlassementCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        Klassement *klassement = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSData *dataIcon = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:klassement.icon]];
        UIImage *imgIcon = [UIImage imageWithData:dataIcon];


        cell.lblPosition.text       = klassement.position;
        cell.lblName.text           = klassement.name;
        cell.lblgamesPlayed.text    = klassement.gamesPlayed;
        cell.lblGamesWon.text       = klassement.gamesWon;
        cell.lblGamesTied.text      = klassement.gamesTied;
        cell.lblGamesLost.text      = klassement.gamesLost;
        cell.lblGoalsPos.text       = klassement.goalsPos;
        cell.lblGoalsNeg.text       = klassement.goalsNeg;
        cell.lblGoalsDiff.text      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", klassement.goalsDiff];
        cell.lblPoints.text         = klassement.points;
        cell.imgClub.image          = imgIcon;

        if([klassement.name isEqualToString:@"KRC Genk"]){
            cell.lblPosition.textColor      = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblName.textColor          = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblgamesPlayed.textColor   = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblGamesTied.textColor     = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblGamesLost.textColor     = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblGoalsDiff.textColor     = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblGoalsNeg.textColor      = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblGoalsPos.textColor      = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblPoints.textColor        = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            cell.lblGamesWon.textColor      = [UIColor colorWithRed:(56/255.0) green:(119/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:100] ;
            return cell;
        }

        return cell;

        //Cells for button 1
    }else if(self.tableView.tag == 1){
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"KalenderCell";

        KalenderCell *cell = (KalenderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass:KalenderCell.class]))
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KalenderCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        Kalender *kalender = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSData *imgDataHome = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kalender.homeIcon]];
        NSData *imgDataAway = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kalender.awayIcon]];

        UIImage *imgHome = [UIImage imageWithData:imgDataHome];
        UIImage *imgAway = [UIImage imageWithData:imgDataAway];

        // Then configure the cell using it ...
        if([kalender.type isEqualToString:@"JPL"]){
            _imgType = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jupiler.png"];
        }else if ([kalender.type isEqualToString:@"EU"]){
            _imgType = [UIImage imageNamed:@"europa.jpg"];
        }else {
            _imgType = nil;
        }

        cell.lblHome.text           = kalender.home;
        cell.lblHomeScore.text      = kalender.homeScore;
        cell.lblAwayScore.text      = kalender.awayScore;
        cell.lblAway.text           = kalender.away;
        cell.lblDate.text           = kalender.date_text;
        cell.lblHour.text           = kalender.hour;
        cell.img_Home.image         = imgHome;
        cell.img_Away.image         = imgAway;
        cell.img_type.image         = _imgType;


        return cell;
    }


    return cell;

}
```

Another problem is that sometimes cells are duplicating itself inside the tableview for 2 or 3 times but when I refresh they tableview is back OK.

I know this is a lot of code. But I hope you want to help me!

Kind regards, and many thanks in advance !

**Screen with the problem**

[image]

Comment: Just remove all the subviews of your cell each time when you load the cell using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. It really works for me. Try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on bellow condition you set blue color

```
    if([klassement.name isEqualToString:@"KRC Genk"]){
      /// set blue color 
    }
```

as it is add else part with black color

like bellow...

```
         else{
            cell.lblPosition.textColor      = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            cell.lblName.textColor          = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            cell.lblgamesPlayed.textColor   = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            cell.lblGamesTied.textColor     = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            cell.lblGamesLost.textColor     = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            cell.lblGoalsDiff.textColor     = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            cell.lblGoalsNeg.textColor      = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            cell.lblGoalsPos.textColor      = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            cell.lblPoints.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor] ;   
            cell.lblGamesWon.textColor      = [UIColor blackColor] ;
            return cell;
         }
```

Comment: i tell the problem which face is when you scroll the tableview at after that your cell change with blue with another cell, right??

Comment: No, I have a pull down to refresh function on my tableview. When this is called I empty my tableview's data and then reload it.  When it's reloaded. other cells besides de 'KRC GENK' cell are blue.

Comment: you reload data means tableview when you click on ranking button??

Comment: No I pull down to refresh like you can do for example in the twitter app to refresh your tweets. I added a screen with the problem

Comment: I hope you understand my problem now. Thanks in advance dude !

Comment: hey dude you put the condition in tag 2 of tableview but not in tag 1 and condition is this if([klassement.name isEqualToString:@"KRC Genk"]) so just try to put this condition in tag 1 also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20683/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-paras-joshi)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in the else part of creating new cell :

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934364/duplicating-subviewsuibutton-and-uiimageview-of-uitableviewcell-contentview-on)

Just try this :

```
if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass:KalenderCell.class]))
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KalenderCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
else
{
   [cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```