# set different images to uitableview cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am making an app in which one of the view has a tableview. Tableview cell has two conditions. There are two images which are going to be set on uitableview cell according to the condition i.e.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *que =[[userqueries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"question"];
    NSString *ans =[[userqueries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer"];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.imageView.image=nil;

        if ((que.length!=0)&&(ans.length!=0)) {
            UIImageView* imag = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 75)];
            imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ques.png"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imag];
            questext = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35)];
            questext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            questext.delegate = self;
            questext.tag = 101;
            questext.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            questext.editable = NO;
            questext.scrollEnabled = YES;
            [cell addSubview:questext];

            anstext = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 37, 300, 35)];
            anstext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            anstext.delegate = self;
            anstext.tag = 102;
            anstext.scrollEnabled = YES;
            anstext.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            anstext.editable = NO;
            [cell addSubview:anstext];
        }
        else {
            UIImageView* imag = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
            imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"answ.png"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imag];

            onlyques = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35)];
            onlyques.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
            [onlyques setScrollEnabled:YES];
            onlyques.delegate = self;
            onlyques.tag = 103;
            onlyques.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            onlyques.editable = NO;
            onlyques.scrollEnabled = YES;
            [cell addSubview:onlyques];
         }
    }
    questext = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    questext.text = que;

    anstext = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    anstext.text = ans;

    onlyques = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    onlyques.text = que;

    return cell;
}
```

But image is not appearing properly. As I scroll up and down the table view ,images get changes automatically.

Please look upon my code and help me in finding the error.[image]

[image]

second image is when I scroll up and down the table view and first image is in the starting.

please help me. if any one knows how to load different images to uitableview cell.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also faced the similar problem. 
See my answer here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934364/duplicating-subviewsuibutton-and-uiimageview-of-uitableviewcell-contentview-on/12970781#12970781][1]

Comment: Remove all subviews of cell before reusing it. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *que =[[userqueries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"question"];
   NSString *ans =[[userqueries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer"];
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil)
   {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      cell.imageView.image=nil;
   } 
   else
   {
      [cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
   }

   if ((que.length!=0)&&(ans.length!=0)) 
   {
        UIImageView* imag = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 75)];
        imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ques.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imag];
        questext = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35)];
        questext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        questext.delegate = self;
        questext.tag = 101;
        questext.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        questext.editable = NO;
        questext.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [cell addSubview:questext];

        anstext = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 37, 300, 35)];
        anstext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        anstext.delegate = self;
        anstext.tag = 102;
        anstext.scrollEnabled = YES;
        anstext.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        anstext.editable = NO;
        [cell addSubview:anstext];
    }
    else 
    {
        UIImageView* imag = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"answ.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imag];

        onlyques = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35)];
        onlyques.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        [onlyques setScrollEnabled:YES];
        onlyques.delegate = self;
        onlyques.tag = 103;
        onlyques.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        onlyques.editable = NO;
        onlyques.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [cell addSubview:onlyques];
     }

     questext = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
     questext.text = que;

     anstext = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
     anstext.text = ans;

     onlyques = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:103];
     onlyques.text = que;

     return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, you should really be using a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, if you plan on adding subviews (see [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info). But, I digress...

There is a simpler way to add an image to your cells (using `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`):

```
if (!cell)
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

if ((que.length!=0)&&(ans.length!=0)) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ques.png"];
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 75);

    ...
}
else {

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"answ.png"];
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);

    ...
}
```

Comment: you might want to add a link to the UIableViewCell class reference... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{
NSString *que =[[userqueries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"question"];
NSString *ans =[[userqueries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer"];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.imageView.image=nil;
}
    if ((que.length!=0)&&(ans.length!=0)) {
        UIImageView* imag = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 75)];
        imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ques.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imag];
        questext = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35)];
        questext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        questext.delegate = self;
        questext.tag = 101;
        questext.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        questext.editable = NO;
        questext.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [cell addSubview:questext];

        anstext = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 37, 300, 35)];
        anstext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        anstext.delegate = self;
        anstext.tag = 102;
        anstext.scrollEnabled = YES;
        anstext.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        anstext.editable = NO;
        [cell addSubview:anstext];
    }

    else
    {
        UIImageView* imag = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"answ.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imag];

        onlyques = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35)];
        onlyques.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        [onlyques setScrollEnabled:YES];
        onlyques.delegate = self;
        onlyques.tag = 103;
        onlyques.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        onlyques.editable = NO;
        onlyques.scrollEnabled = YES;
        [cell addSubview:onlyques];
     }

questext = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
questext.text = que;

anstext = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
anstext.text = ans;

onlyques = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:103];
onlyques.text = que;

return cell;

}
```

What i have done here is putting your image changing condition outside

```
if(cell == nil){ } statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, you have to place } before when call is created

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   
      *)indexPath


       {
    NSString *que =[[userqueries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"question"];
    NSString *ans =[[userqueries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer"];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   
     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
        cell.imageView.image=nil;

        if ((que.length!=0)&&(ans.length!=0)) {
            UIImageView* imag = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 75)];
            imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ques.png"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imag];
            questext = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35)];
            questext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            questext.delegate = self;
            questext.tag = 101;
            questext.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            questext.editable = NO;
            questext.scrollEnabled = YES;
            [cell addSubview:questext];

            anstext = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 37, 300, 35)];
            anstext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            anstext.delegate = self;
            anstext.tag = 102;
            anstext.scrollEnabled = YES;
            anstext.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            anstext.editable = NO;
            [cell addSubview:anstext];
        }

        else
        {
            UIImageView* imag = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
            imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"answ.png"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imag];

            onlyques = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35)];
            onlyques.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
            [onlyques setScrollEnabled:YES];
            onlyques.delegate = self;
            onlyques.tag = 103;
            onlyques.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            onlyques.editable = NO;
            onlyques.scrollEnabled = YES;
            [cell addSubview:onlyques];
         }

    questext = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    questext.text = que;

    anstext = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    anstext.text = ans;

    onlyques = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    onlyques.text = que;

    return cell;

}
```

Hope this helps you..