# How to remove UITableViewCell's subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created imageview to display image on cellForRowAtIndexPath method. and I add imageview in Cell as subview. But when I reload my tableview at that time the image in cell does not reload. following is my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrcathatname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 7, 35, 35)];
    [cell addSubview:imgView];

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrCatName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

So, I want to remove my imageview to reload image properly.

How can I do that?

Comment: Add the subviews to cell or cell.contentView??

Comment: Try using [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

Comment: Check link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934364/duplicating-subviewsuibutton-and-uiimageview-of-uitableviewcell-contentview-on/12970781#12970781

Comment: are you getting image from server url?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add subviews to cell as :

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

You can remove that subviews using code :

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgView.tag  = 111;



[cell.contentView addSubView:imgView];
}
imgView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView ViewWithTag:111];

[imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 7, 35, 35)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrcathatname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


cell.textLabel.text = [arrCatName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

Try this

Comment: have you tried this i have updated the again pls check. and let me know if you have any more issues