# UITableViewCell content merging on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

When i open ViewController i can see normal UITableView with correct content as shown in below image

[image: before scrolling tableview]

and when i tried to scroll up and down then suddenly contents merged like this below image.
[image: after scrolling tableview]
please help me to solve this issue

My code is

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[announcement valueForKey:@"title"] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UILabel *label = nil;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];



        }
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    [label setTag:1];


    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];



    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [[[announcement valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if (!label)
        label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:93.0/255.0 green:93.0/255.0 blue:93.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontHelveticaNeueBold size:cell.textLabel.font.pointSize];



    label.text=[[announcement valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


            NSString *text =[[announcement valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

            CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

            CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

           return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);

}
```

please help

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934364/duplicating-subviewsuibutton-and-uiimageview-of-uitableviewcell-contentview-on/12970781#12970781

Comment: ok checking..........

Comment: your own post and answer, is that working for you? like removing cell content from view?

Comment: Yes, did you try that? But i know it is an instant fix and not the exact method.

Comment: but that fix is working fine and good to go..thanks a lot @AnushaK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem may be because of the cell reusing. The best method of working with tableView cells is customise cell. Then you need not add UI elements in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

For instant solving in your current code, remove the existing subview in the case of reusing,

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: coool..... its working....thnks  . if you take freelance projects pls let me know

Comment: @AnushaK, i tried this way but not working for me, any other solutions? if so please make reply

Comment: i fixed, my issue by adding following code     cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %ld",(long)indexPath.row];

Answer (score 1):

As you are using reusable cells, and for each cell weather it's reusable or freshly created you are creating a new label and adding it over the cell's content view.

For a freshly created cell adding a label is not an issue.

But the issue occurs when the cell is reused, already containing one label and again another label is created which comes over the previous label, and thus is responsible for overlapping of one label with other.

To resolve this issue you have two options-

1) update the content of reusable cells label with the data of the label for current index path

2) in case of reusable cell release previous label and create a new one, initialize with the data for the present row.

Using 2nd approach I have updated your implementation of cell creating handler as -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UILabel *label = nil;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }

    label = [[cell contentView] viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    if(label ! = nil)
          [label removeFRomSuperView];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    [label setTag:indexPath.row];

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [[[announcement valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:93.0/255.0 green:93.0/255.0 blue:93.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontHelveticaNeueBold size:cell.textLabel.font.pointSize];



    label.text=[[announcement valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];

    [label release];

    return cell;
}
```

You can use above implementation to resolve your issue of overlapping due to multiple label existing on a reusable cell.